# How do I improve efficiency of my code? Im trying to sort a list

Tags: python, list, performance, sorting

This is what I've written for list input and sorting it. It generates TLE error.

```
n=int(input())
l=[]
for i in range(n):
    a=int(input())
    l.append(a)
    l.sort()
for j in l:
    print(j)
```

This is the code that got accepted

```
import sys


n = int(input().strip())
unsorted = []
unsorted_i = 0
for unsorted_i in range(n):
   unsorted_t = str(input().strip())
   unsorted.append(unsorted_t)

unsorted.sort(key = lambda x : int(x))
for u in unsorted:
    print(u)
```

why did the person take the list elements as string first and then convert them to int. Does it have any significant advantage?

Comment: What's a TLE error?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Time Limit Exceeded I guess.

Comment: There's no "advantage". (Arguably, there's usually a "disadvantage" if you want to do anything with the numbers later...)

Comment: It's probably taking forever because you're running `.sort` a very large number of times (`n`).

Answer (score 1):

The second code is horrible. Taking list elements as a string first and converting them for each comparison during sorting is straight-up awful.

Your code is good, you just made the mistake of sorting every time you add an element to the list. You should only sort once when you have all the elements in the list, i.e. un-intend the `l.sort()` line and take it out of the for loop.